# PieChart not appearing in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using google [**piechart**](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart), Here it is visible on all browser except IE in document mode ie8. If I changed to other document mode like IE7 or IE9, its appeared, but if I set document mode ie8 its not visible.

How may I fix this bug.

Thanks for you advice.

Comment: Are you using any canvas element in your code? Consider adding some fiddle too.

Comment: @SumitGera : See examples mentioned in the link above, a fiddle is not necessary.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4u7FZ/ here the demo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I do not have any issues using real `IE8` web browser. It works both for normal view and compatibility view without issue. No solution is required.*

**However... if you refresh the webpage, then the pie chart objects no longer appear.**

The solution in that case is to contact the webpage administrator for that page by directly clicking the **Report a Bug** found at the bottom of that webpage.  Note, the URL *seen for that link* will not be used, so that's another bug as well.

The only method to see the pie object again is to restart the browser.

**Edit:** It seems [**there is a history**](https://www.google.com/search?q=Google+Pie+chart+not+showing+in+IE8) of Google Pie chart failing in `IE8`.

**Possible Bug:**

This screenshot shows all cookies from that webpage are being block by my standard IE8 security settings. I went so far as to add this site to trusted, but no change... cookies are blocked! Changing the protocol to `http://` does not help since Google redirects to secure `https://`

[image]

The above screenshot is produced by clicking the Red Eye seen in the browsers status bar.

Make sure your status bar is enabled via setting it from `Menu>>>Tools>>>Toolbars>>>Status bar`

---

**Workaround Solution:**

I figured out how to get the lost pie chart after switching document modes in IE8.

To duplicate failure, use native IE8 Developer Tools and access console.
You should be in IE8 Browser Mode and IE8 Document Mode.
Now change to IE7 Document Mode.
After the page reloads, you will see pie chart.
Change Document Mode back to IE8 and the page will fail to load pie chart.

To recover, change Browser Mode to IE8 Compatibility View, then change back to IE8 Browser (normal) mode.

***The pie chart has returned!***